# How to display toast/alert with in the component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast, alert

I have a aura component with in the opportunity detail page and i'm trying to display toast/ alert message with in the component.Is there any way to display toast/alert message with in the component instead of detail page.

```
$A.get('e.force:showToast').setParams
({
  "title": "Success",
   "message": "SKU has been deleted successfully!",
   "type": "success",
}).fire();
```

For Reference:
[image]

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without a custom implementation AFAIK.

`force:showToast` event is (*refer to documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation)*)

> 1. used to display page-level toasts
> 2. used to display a message below the header at the top of a view
> 3. handled by the one.app container.

AFAIK, it isn't built at platform level to make it localized to individual custom components. You might have to build your own custom implementation display local error message within the component.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of force:showToast, it will displays a message below the header at the top of a view.

If you want to show message on component itself , i would suggest to use [ui:message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:message/example) , which will show the message in below format on aura component.
[image]
**Note** : This tag is only available for Aura component not for LWC.

Comment: Please note `ui:message` is deprecated as of API version 47.0 and the recommended approach is to migrate to LWC and use the lightning/platformShowToastEvent module (which is nothing but toast message).